For $f:G_1 \to G_2$ a group homomorphism, Prove that $|\{(x,y) \in G_1 \times G_2: f(x^n) = y^n\}| \ \equiv \ 0\mod |G_1|$
I am stuck on the following problem which is from Ex-2.26(b) of these notes.

Given $f: G_1 \to G_2$ , a group homomorphism, Where $G_1 , G_2$ are finite groups and Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer. Then prove that: $$|\{(x,y) \in G_1 \times G_2: f(x^n) = y^n\}| \ \equiv 0\mod |G_1|$$

What I've tried is considering some group action like : $G_1$ on  $\ \{(x,y) \in G_1 \times G_2: f(x^n) = y^n\} \ $ defined by $g * (x,y) = (g \ x \ {g}^{-1},\ f(g) \ y \ f({g}^{-1}))$ and what I've noticed is for $(x,y)$, its orbit is in correspondence to the conjugacy class of $x$ in $G_1. \ $And that's a dead end for me.
So I would like to confirm if this is the 'right' action to consider here and if so how do I make further progress with it, If not then what is the proper way to do these kind of problems?
Thanks

Notice that $f(x^n)=f(x)^n$. Also, the set of $y$-values for a given $x$ is closed under conjugation by $f(x)$.

Why is the set of y values closed under conjugation by f(x), like if ord(G_1)=ord(G_2)=n then anything would work right?

Oh my apologies, I misunderstood. I agree that the set of y values that work for a given x are invariant under conjugation by f(x) if that's what you meant by closed? I am still not able to decipher what conjugating the set of y by f(x) leads to..

Hints: reduce to the case $f$ is surjective. Do it for $n=1$ first.

@SteveD when $f$ is surjective and $n=1$ then we can select a $y \in G_2$ there will be $|ker f|$ values of it satisfying the equality so we would get the size of the given set to be $|G_2| * |ker f| = |G_1|$ so it indeed checks out, but i think in the general case what if we don't have surjectivity and there are elements outside the image that satisfy $f(x^n)=y^n$

If you were counting pairs $(x,z)$ such that $f(x^n)=z$, how would you do that?

@SteveD in case f is surjective we can say that  $f(x^n)=f(z) \implies x^n ker f = z \  ker f$ so all the z that work belong in $x^n ker f$.  i still have no clue how we do it for the general case

In the case I described, $z$ has to belong to $f(G_1)$ right? Let me describe the solution in my case: we can reduce to the case $f(G_1)=G_2$ since other elements contribute no pairs. Now using $f(x^n)=f(x)^n$, for an arbitrary $z\in f(G_1)$, how many pairs have second coordinate $z$? It's $|\ker(f)|$ times the number of elements $g$ with $g^n=z$. Now sum all these up.

Said another way, how many pairs start with $x$? Well, $z$ is completely determined by $x$, so exactly $1$!

@SteveD wait, i didnt understand the part z is completely determined by $x$, if its not injective for a given $z$ we can have many $x$'s in the first coordinate , and also i have trouble in summing up all the $g^n=z$, if you could pls elaborate more on that

Why would we care if it's injective? Given $x$, there is one $z$, specifically the element $z=f(x^n)$. I've given you two ways to count the pairs.  Please spend some time thinking about this until you understand it.

@SteveD for double counting ${(x,z) : f(x^n)=z}$ I got the that $|G_1| = |ker f| \sum_{z \in \ f(G_1)} |{g \in G_2 : g^n=z}|$ , I am still not able to decipher the general problem, for me I think the $y^n$ is creating the difficulties

Have you done the previous exercise (2.25), especially part (c)?

@SteveD Ah no, I did all the other bits other than (c)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Summarizing the hints I gave in chat:
Show that if $H$ is a subgroup of the finite group $G$, and $Y=\{g\in G\mid g^n\in H\}$, then $|H|$ divides $|Y|$.

 Show that $Y$ is the union of equivalence classes from 2.25. Use 2.25(c) to conclude.

Continuing with $H\le G$, let $Z=\{(h,g)\mid h^n=g^n\}$. Show that $|H|$ divides $|Z|$.

 Apply the previous result with $H\times G$ the larger group, and the diagonal subgroup $D=\{(h,h)\mid h\in H\}$ the smaller group. Then $Z$ is just the $Y$ from above, and $|D|=|H|$.

Solve the problem when $\ker(f)=\{1\}$.

 In this case, let $G=G_2$ and $H=f(G_1)$. The previous part shows if $A=\{(f(g_1),g_2)\mid f(g_1)^n=g_2^n\}$, then $|H|=|G_1|$ divides $|A|$. This is enough, since $f$ is injective.

Solve the problem.

 Let $B=\{(g_1,g_2)\mid f(g_1)^n=g_2^n\}$. From the previous part, $|A|$ is divisible by $|f(G_1)|$. Every element of $A$ has $|\ker(f)|$ preimages in $B$. Thus $B$ is divisible by $|A|\cdot|\ker(f)|=|G_1|$.

